# What was this "light" that looked like a star moving repeating from point A to B for about 5 mins

Tags: star, orbit, rotation, night-sky, satellite

I was looking in the sky one night about 9:45. There was what looked to be a shooting star but much slower and brighter more like a satellite. It was moving (from standing on earth) it looked like a couple of feet. It would then disappear for about 10-15 seconds and reappear from the original spot it started from and do the exact thing as described before.tried to take pictures but it wouldn't show .from point A to point B then back to point A 10 seconds later after disappearing

Comment: Probably a series of Starlink satellites.  You can check for a recent pass for your location on sites like https://heavens-above.com/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What could be an explanation for a satellite-like moving light in the night sky that dims over time](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/50156/what-could-be-an-explanation-for-a-satellite-like-moving-light-in-the-night-sky)

Comment: I’ve seen the star link satellites  before . It was nothing like it. Iit was 1 single light the brightness of a satellite, that would slowly move (in the same pattern once returned) , disappear, then reappear from the point it was first seen.